# Make a laptop act as a second monitor through usb

Tags: windows-10, usb, multiple-monitors

I have a Windows 10 2-in-1 Laptop/Tablet that have a micro-usb port on it but no ethernet port. Is there a way to make it act as a second monitor for my main computer. I tested the **Projecting to this PC** tool that is included in Windows 10. It works but through my wifi network and it is pretty slow. I wonder if it is possible to do the same thing via a USB to micro-USB cable using a software like [spacedesk](https://spacedesk.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot connect a USB host to another USB host - that's one reason why the plugs don't fit, to prevent you from even trying.

What you want is not possible. Spacedesk (& anything else like it) is designed to work over some type of 'net' connection, wired or wireless.

Answer (score 0):

From [this Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-a-laptop-as-a-monitor-for-a-desktop-computer), no, you cannot take a working laptop, shut it down, plug it to power and then connect it through a cable to another PC and have the laptop function as a monitor.

> The laptop GPU typically has two or three outputs. One of them is connected to the built-in screen. The remaining ones are VGA/HDMI/DisplayPort outputs for additional external monitors. Since **they’re outputs, not inputs**, and since they’re connected to the GPU (not straight to the internal display panel!), **there’s no way to use them to drive the internal LCD panel from an external signal source**.

Quora suggests that you could repurpose a broken or unused laptop into a monitor by repurposing the hardware, but I believe that has nothing to do with what you're looking for.

Unfortunately, I don't think the hardware of a laptop is set up to function this way: there is no input port or accompanying hardware to work the monitor other than the direct connection between the screen and the laptop's GPU.

Comment: I am more searching for a Windows software that could make the connection. The second laptop does not need to be off.

Comment: I tried to explain in my answer that there is a hard limitation in the hardware that you cannot overcome with software. Nothing can "make the connection" because your laptop does not have an input to connect a cable to. USB is **not** a video interface. There might exist "USB to HDMI" or similar adapters that contain a driver along the cable, but again the issue boils down to hardware, not software. The only solution software could offer is relaying the video over a wireless connection like WiFi, which you already stated you have a method of doing, but it is unsatisfactory to your needs.

Comment: I understand that USB is not a video interface, but it can transfer files and data. Imagine a software that simulates a second screen, transforms the video stream into data and send it through usb. At the other end a "client program" would receive the data and display it as a video !

Comment: So are you looking to solely duplicate your main screen onto the laptop rather than extending the display to it? (Extending meaning that the second screen is its own screen rather than a duplicate of the first.)

Comment: No I want to extend the display. My idea was to simulate the "extension" of the screen in the program and send the output to the other laptop. But if two computer can't "talk" through USB then it is impossible..

Answer (score 0):

> It works but through my wifi network and it is pretty slow. I wonder if it is possible to do the same thing via a USB to micro-USB cable.

Try using a *wired* connection to your router (both devices) instead of Wifi.

Comment: I do not have an Ethernet port on my tablet.

Comment: Get a USB to Ethernet adapter or compatible dock.

Comment: @LawrenceC A USB-to-Ethernet is a great thing, but in application like this where the user is trying to increase the speed of the network connection, it might not offer a great advantage. USB-to-Ethernet will always be throttled compared to straight Ethernet, and whether it is faster than just WiFi is a coin toss.